# module not found error while testing angular app with webpack externals

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, single-spa

I have an external utility module created for using across all the angular micro-frontends. The unit test cases were running absolutely fine in the angular apps till I imported this external utility module.

```
import { userPreferencesHandler } from "@org/utility";
```

Below is the error I am getting
[image]

The extra webpack configuration is written as below:

```
const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require("single-spa-angular/lib/webpack").default;
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = (config, options) => {
    const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(config, options);

    // Feel free to modify this webpack config however you'd like to
    return merge(singleSpaWebpackConfig, {
        externals: ["@org/utility"],
    });
};
```

How to fix this issue on running npm test command?

Comment: Have you installed the package?

Comment: does not need installation as it is not an npm package